# Переставить большую цифру с меньшей предыдущей в числе местами

Tags: c#, массивы

``Столкнулся с задачей - Найти ближайшую большую целую цифру в числе и переставить её местами с предыдущей, если таковой нет (то есть по факту, если **number < 1**, то результат **null**).
То есть : **23** - **манипуляция** - **32**  и то же самое **4056** - **манипуляция** - **4065** , то есть срабатывает только 1 раз. Не понимаю как это сделать в отсутствии Stack и List. Пытался написать что-то по типу int[] array = number.Select(x => x).ToArray(), но это скорее какой-то бред.

Пустой метод выглядит вот так

```
    public static int? TheBiggest(int number)
    {

       
    }
```

Код :

```
  char[] digit = number.ToString().ToArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < digit.Length; i++)
        {
            if (digit[i] < digit[i + 1])
            {
                char temp = '0';
                temp = digit[i];
                digit[i] = digit[i + 1];
                digit[i + 1] = temp;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        //конвертирование и вывод данных?
```

Comment: Хотел бы понять как это корректно сделать.

Comment: Начните с того, что освойте перебор всех цифр в числе: while(number>0) { var digit = number / 10; Console.WriteLine(digit); number = number / 10; }` Дальше логика несложная будет

Comment: @AK, это понятно - здесь речь о том, как разбить и переставить, ведь подходит сюда массив типа char[], но не имеет встроенных возможностей как у string. Меня это в первую очередь и озадачило.

Comment: Зато у char[] есть огромное преимущество перед строкой - строка иммутабельна, её не изменишь, а в массиве чар очень просто переставить местами два элемента. Вам именно запрещено использовать любые структуры данных кроме массива? Т.е. List и Stack - никак нельзя? Вы как-то об этом невзначай упоминаете, нет чёткого понимания что можно а что нельзя. Так-то задача несложная.

Comment: В условиях задачи написано, что можно использовать только базовые (то есть Collection.Generic нельзя). Так что да - только массивы .

Comment: Начните с например `int[] digits = number.ToString().Select(c => c - '0').ToArray(); Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", digits));`

Comment: @aepot , да давно начал - просто я не знаю как это все корректно разыграть без Linq .

Comment: Сделайте как угодно с привлечением каких угодно структур данных - и покажите нам. А когда сделаете - скажите, что конкретно непонятно как от чего избавиться. Пока похоже, что вы просто хотите чтобы всё сделали за вас - и не подсказки дали, а конкретный код. Этот ступор, когда не можешь написать никакой код (у журналистов и писателей есть даже название "боязнь чистого листа") - его нужно разрывать всегда сразу и без рассусоливаний: пишите хоть какой код. Никаких "я сдаюсь". Вы говорите что понимаете алгоритм но со стеком? Вот его и напишите.

Comment: @AK , "чтобы всё сделал за вас" - как раз таки я стараюсь это больше всего и избегать, но с C# как минимум так не получается (себе во вред) из-за соблазна полазить по форумам и стокам, но в данном случае я бы хотел (мысль на тот момент была выражена не корректно) **понять**, как написать (уже приложил свой small code с массивом) алгоритм, чтобы он грубо говоря был в "1 строчку" и при этом чтобы выполнялись условия в виде неиспользования Linq и других библиотек.

Comment: Не вижу нигде приложенного кода, разве пустой цикл. И ссылок нет на какие-нибудь онлайн-фиддлеры. Покажите работающий  вариант на массивах или на List, без linq. Взяли цикл while, взяли List, обошли все циферки, прошлись for нашли максимальную циферку, сделали swap -- этот вариант-то вы смогли захардкодить или на словах готовы, а по факту ходите по кругу и думаете, как бы это же сделать без List'а?

Comment: Пока не видно реальных вопросов ("как узнать сколько цифр в числе, чтобы задать длину массива и избавиться от List'a"), видно только вот эту руминацию, постоянное хождение по одному кругу -- а такие руминации надо беспощадно обрывать, чтобы не зациклиться.  Не можете написать в одну строчку - напишите в триста строчек, упростите себе задачу. Пока она решена "никак". Решите "хоть как". Потом начните плясать от этого решения, пытаясь понять, какие шаги лишние, что можно упростить. Скульптор берёт глыбу мрамора и отсекает всё лишнее - ну вот и вы так.

Answer (score 1):

https://ideone.com/zgujh7

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
  private static int? SwapMax(int n)
  {
    var a = n.ToString().ToCharArray();
    var c = a.Max();
    var i = Array.IndexOf(a, c);
    if (i == 0) return null;
    a[i] = a[i-1];
    a[i-1] = c;
    return int.Parse(new String(a));
  }
    
  public static void Main()
  {
    foreach (var n in new int[] {23, 32, 4056, 4056456, 8, 99, 89, 98, 103})
      Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1}", n, SwapMax(n));
  }
}
```

```
23 => 32
32 => 
4056 => 4065
4056456 => 4065456
8 => 
99 => 
89 => 98
98 => 
103 => 130
```

PS: Если linq нельзя, придётся максимум самому написать.